# Binding from Different Selected Listbox Items

Tags: c#, binding, listbox

**Intro: **
I'm working with a standard MVVM framework and I have two listboxes from which I want to be able to select one item from. The listboxes are binding to different ObservableCollections of the same class.

After binding to the ViewModel, I want to be able to represent the selected Item on the same window, from either of the Listbox depending on which item I am selecting.

**ViewModel -**

```
    private KisesaSearchResultViewModel _selectedPerson;
    public KisesaSearchResultViewModel SelectedPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedPerson;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedPerson = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPerson");
        }
    }

    private KisesaSearchResultViewModel _selectedSearch;
    public KisesaSearchResultViewModel SelectedSearch
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedSearch;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedSearch = value;
            SelectedPerson = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedSearch");
        }
    }

    private KisesaSearchResultViewModel _selectedMatch;
    public KisesaSearchResultViewModel SelectedMatch
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedMatch;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedMatch = value;
            SelectedPerson = _selectedMatch;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedMatch");
        }
    }
```

**XAML -**

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MatchedMembers, Mode=OneWay}" 
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SearchResult}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSearch}">
    </ListBox>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedMatchList, Mode=OneWay}" 
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SearchResult}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMatch}">
    </ListBox>
```

**I want to display information as such:**

```
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path= SelectedPerson.FullName}" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Style="{StaticResource PInfo}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource Info}" Margin="30,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson.Age}"/>
```

**Question:**
I need to have SelectedSearch and SelectedPerson because I want to be able to change SelectedPerson independtly. At this point, the SelectedPerson is getting set by the SelectedSearch setter, but it is not binding to the Textblocks. I am using OnPropertyChanged, but do I need to do something else like use an Event Handler? Also, slightly unrelated, but can I restrict a WPF window so that only one item from two different Listboxes is selected at a time?

Comment: Are you setting the DataContext to your viewmodel? Are you getting a binding error in the output window of VS?

Comment: No I am not getting a binding error and I am setting the DataContext. this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();. If I bind directly from the variable that gets set to the listbox selected item everything works fine. It's that extra re-setting that messes something up.